# Seguimiento con git

Tags: git

Una vez que inicio el repositorio poniendo en consola git init, como hago para despues desactivarlo y dejar de trabajar con git, osea, dejar de tener el seguimiento en los archivos ?

Comment: Estas en windows? Estas usando la consola de git?
Podrias usar el cmd si estas en windows.
No estoy seguro de cuales son las diferencias de la consola de git con el cmd, pero seguramente la consola de git ya tiene las mismas funcionalidades que ofrece cmd. No hay que enredarse con eso. Espero te sirva

Answer (score 1):

Las acciones realizadas por `git` en el control de versiones, en general, están dentro del a carpeta `.git`.

Si eliminas esa carpeta, efectivamente estarás eliminando todo el control de versiones (sea este el repositorio original de un proyecto o un clon.

En Linux, te situas en la carpeta que está bajo control de git y ejecuta:

```
rm -rf .git
```

En Windows, puedes eliminar la carpeta en el explorador de archivos. <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>del</kbd> eliminará una carpeta para siempre, sin pasar por la papelera de reciclaje.

Esta carpeta está oculta, debes configurar tu explorador para ver archivos ocultos y del sistema para que te la muestre.

[image: Carpeta .git en el explorador de Windows]

### Advertencia

Eliminar esta carpeta te va a dejar sin historial, sin *commit*, *push*, *pull*, etc. Perderás el estado de la copia actual y del repositorio completo. En general perderás todo el control proporcionado por git. Hazlo solo si estás seguro de lo que haces.